# How can I compile/package a Java .jar as a Mac OS X command-line tool?

Tags: java, macos, packaging, executable-jar, command-line-tool

I'm not a Java programmer, but I often use a Java program someone else wrote, that's currently packaged as a .jar file, that I invoke from the Mac OS X Terminal as:

```
$ java -jar /path/to/jarfile/myJavaCommand.jar -some other arguments ...
```

I'd much rather be able to invoke it like any other command-line tool:

```
$ myJavaCommand -some other arguments ...
```

I have the .java sources and a Makefile that turns them into the .class files and packages them into the .jar.

I have found documentation for turning Java programs into Mac OS X double-clickable ".app" bundles, but I don't think that's what I want because I want a single executable file that I can drop into, say, `/usr/local/bin` so I can easily invoke it from the Terminal, with varying arguments (and without typing in long paths).

I don't want to solve this with a separate shell script or shell alias because I move this tool around from machine to machine, and prefer not to have to copy around a shell script or modify the shell environment on the other machines.

So is there a way to compile/package a Java program as a single-file Mac OS X command-line tool?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't. The shell script approach is pretty much it.

Your java code is not natively executable, it is executed by the JVM. In addition, the jar file is actually a zip archive ... so the shell simply has no idea what to do with it what so ever.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [YAJSW](http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/), which wraps Java apps for easier launching on native platforms.

You'll still have a big directory of stuff to copy around; I don't know if it will solve your specific questions on OS X, but we use it for Windows launching and it works well.